# Threshold on duration in a log file

Tags: python, parsing

I want to parse a log file with a python script to highlight lines with time more than a particular duration, say 50 ms.

So I have already use the code below to convert it to csv, but this way needs some data cleaning.
Any suggestions for a better way is appreciated.

```
with open(r"5.160.146.140.log", encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f, open('logfile.csv', 'w') as f2: 
    writer = csv.writer(f2)
    writer.writerow(['index', 'from', 'icmp_seq', 'ttl', 'time']) # column header

    i = 0
    for line in f:
        writer.writerow([i] + line.rstrip().split(' '))
        i += 1
        if i == 10000:
            break
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use pandas for this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('logfile.csv', sep=' ', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
print(df.head())
```

You can also filter the cases you want (this is just the idea, you need to adapt to your reality):

```
df['time'] = df['time'].str.replace(' ms', '')
df['time'] = pd.to_numeric(df['time'])
print(df[df['time'] > 50])
```

Note also that you will need first to treat this column as numeric since you have "ms" in all of them.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html